# How do I widen a knife cut?

Tags: edges

I'm trying to make a lazy river in a flat plane, and the first step I can think of is to thicken a line so I can extrude it downwards. I've tried using bevel on the line to thicken it, but the line ends up being of uneven width. Is there a trick I can use or a different approach to get an even-width channel?

[image: Bevel knife cut]

Comment: if you bevel one of your edge it should keep the same thickness all along, are your sure that the scale is applied?

Comment: What do you mean by scale?

Comment: in Object mode, check the scale of your object in the N panel, if it's not 1/1/1 press Ctrl A (Apply) > Scale, and bevel again

Answer (score 10):

I think I've figured it out, ironically. I worked on it for hours before this, but I just realized there's a "Width Type" parameter on the bevel, and when set to "Width" it keeps the width of the line even like I wanted.
Thanks everyone for the pointers!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

add a plane, subdivide it a lot,

add a beziercurve (your river), give it a bevel, then convert it to mesh, give it a subdivision modifier

then add these modifiers to your plane and you get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for replying! It's my bad, I should've specified - I want to keep the mesh low-poly. I'll definitely look into curves more now, though!